# Monitoring files for modifications

Tags: julia

I’m trying to write a simple code that continuously checks when files in a given folder are modified and, upon modification, triggers a function.

I've added a MWE below, it "works" but I was wondering if

- there are libraries or utilities that I should look into that help for such a problem?
- there was a cleaner way to have something running continuously until some event (here an interruption)

```julia
files_and_times = Dict{String, Int}()
for (root, _, files) ∈ walkdir(dirpath)
    for f ∈ files
        fpath = joinpath(root, f)
        files_and_times[fpath] = stat(fpath).mtime
    end
end
try
    while true
        for (f, t) ∈ files_and_times
            cur_t = stat(f).mtime
            if cur_t > t
                files_and_times[f] = cur_t
                println("file $f was modified")
            end
        end
        sleep(0.5)
    end
catch x
    if isa(x, InterruptException)
        println("Shutting down.")
    else
        throw(x)
    end
end
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at [FileWatching](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/FileWatching/)?

Comment: You might be interested in [this discourse thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/resources-for-running-julia-routines-in-the-background-24-7/7237). Note, the general conclusion is that Julia is not really geared towards continuous monitoring programs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know what I was looking for which is why I wasn't aware of FileWatching which seems to solve the problem @rickhg12hs. Re discourse thread, thanks for the pointer, the use case I have in mind would be for short periods of time (definitely not 24/7) so Julia might just be ok for it (I hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments by @rickhg12hs and @Colin_T_Bowers effectively answer my question. Posting an answer to close the question.

- [FileWatching](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/FileWatching/) seems to be precisely what I was looking for,
- The package [Revise](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl) seems to have good examples showing how to use it and,
- [this discourse thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/resources-for-running-julia-routines-in-the-background-24-7/7237) discusses limitations.